# C++ lvalue and rvalue question.(move semantic)

Tags: c++

Here is the code from the book

```
LargeType randomItem1( const vector<LargeType> & arr )
{
    return arr[ randomInt( 0, arr.size( )-1)]; 
}

const LargeType & randomItem2( const vector<LargeType> & arr ) 
{
    return arr[ randomInt( 0, arr.size( )-1)]; 
}
vector<LargeType> vec; 
...
LargeType item1 = randomItem1( vec );// copy 
LargeType item2 = randomItem2( vec );// copy
const LargeType & item3 = randomItem2( vec ); // no copy
```

```
vector<int> partialSum( const vector<int> & arr ) 
{
    vector<int> result( arr.size( ) ); 
    result[ 0 ] = arr[ 0 ];
    for( int i = 1; i < arr.size( ); ++i ) 
    {
        result[ i ] = result[ i-1]+ arr[ i ];
    } 
    return result;
}

vector<int> vec; 
...
vector<int> sums = partialSum( vec ); // Copy in old C++; move in C++11
```

The book says `LargeType randomItem1( const vector<LargeType> & arr )` does not call move semantics while `vector<int> partialSum( const vector<int> & arr )` does. Why is this happening?
I understand that `return arr[ randomInt( 0, arr.size( )-1)];` is an lvalue since `arr` itself is reference of object but isn't `result` an object too? the book says `return result` is temporary, however it is declared at line 3 at second code box.

want to know why return result is temporary even if it is declared and have name.

Comment: Which book are you talking about?

Comment: You might want to read the section named [Automatic move from local variables and parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return). Basically, `return variable_name;` is a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fucntion `randomItem1` does not own `arr`, which means it is not allowed to move `arr[ randomInt( 0, arr.size( )-1)]` out of the function.

In `partialSum` the function owns `result` so it is free to move it out of the function once the function ends.

The rule is that all function local variables can be treated as rvalues for the purpose of the return statement and only are considered an lvalue if no constructor can be found when considered as an rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what NathanOliver said, `vector<int> sums = partialSum( vec );` may result in neither copy nor move because of [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).